# How to call game object in Unity's C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and C# and have a confusion. I am writing a game with 2 players selection, and the chosen one would be the controller's character. My program flows go like
 `player choose a character -> pass the index of selected character -> hide other character except the chosen one`

I implemented the following codes

```
public GameObject[] characters;
public Transform playerStartPosition;
public string menuScene = "Character Selection Menu";
private string selectedCharacterDataName = "SelectedCharacter";
int selectedCharacter;
public GameObject playerObject;

void Start()
{
    selectedCharacter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(selectedCharacterDataName,0);

    
   if (selectedCharacter == 0){
       characters[0].setActive(true);
       characters[1].setActive(false);
}else {
    characters[0].setActive(false);
    characters[1].setActive(true);

    }
   
}
```

and it made the CS1061 error. How I can declare to call the character object?
Great thanks

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add your code to the question rather than an image of it.

Comment: Sorry for the impoliteness. Just added back the codes and would beware in future post!

Comment: That is a simple **TYPO**: It is [`GameObject.SetActive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) .. not `setActive`

Comment: Just realise... how stupid I am. Thanks mate! @derHugo

Comment: @CeliaChan I wouldn't say stupid ;) Just learn to understand your compiler errors and get more familiar with and with first consulting the [Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/) especially with the most basic types.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean actually rendering the chosen player object to the screen and creating an instance of the player object?
If you do you can use the Instantiate method, and handle which player is instantiated with the same logic based on the user selection

If it is a 3D object you would pass the object prefab then the location and rotation of the object

```
Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: Also it is probably important to note you will need to pass these objects into the GameObject Array in the start method so that they are available for the player to pick and the array is not empty.

Comment: I actually tried this method to render but I do not know how to link up the the controller object (included camera those) to the instantiated object. Or if the instantiated player IS in the controller object it would inherit those? Sorry fo rthe stupid question.

Comment: Depending on the style of game, for example first person, You could instantiate your player character at the vector3 location and quaternion of the camera, then make the the camera a child of the player so that when you update the players location on the screen the camera follows.  Also use the .addComponent<Script> method, to add the controller script to your newly instantiated player.